# Django Google reCAPTCHA not working - form data submits but page redirects to 404 page, how to solve?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, recaptcha

I build a contact page with a django where is two forms. When I submit contact page form with google reCaptcha verification form data is submitting to the backend or admin panel but it redirecting my page to 404 page after submitting the form with google recaptcha.

## my html forms for contact.html

```
{% block contactpage %}

    <!--====== PAGE TITLE  PART START ======-->
    {% for cslider in cslider %}
    <div class="page-title-area">
        <div class="section__bg" style="background-image: url('{{cslider.slider_image.url}}');"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="page-title-content text-center">
                        <h3 class="title">Contact</h3>
                        <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
                            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Accueil</a></li>
                                <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Contact</li>
                            </ol>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <!--====== PAGE TITLE  PART ENDS ======-->

    <!--====== CONTACT US PART START ======-->
    
    <section class="contact-us-area contact-us-page">
        <div class="section__bg" style="background-image: url('{% static 'images/black-elegant-background-with-copy-space.jpg' %}');"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <!--Hidden Message Alert Area-->
                <div class="container">
                    {% for message in messages %}
                    <div class="alert alert-primary alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="bi bi-exclamation-triangle-fill flex-shrink-0 me-2" viewBox="0 0 16 16" role="img" aria-label="Warning:">
                            <path d="M8.982 1.566a1.13 1.13 0 0 0-1.96 0L.165 13.233c-.457.778.091 1.767.98 1.767h13.713c.889 0 1.438-.99.98-1.767L8.982 1.566zM8 5c.535 0 .954.462.9.995l-.35 3.507a.552.552 0 0 1-1.1 0L7.1 5.995A.905.905 0 0 1 8 5zm.002 6a1 1 0 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 0-2z"/>
                        </svg>
                        <strong>Félicitations !! &nbsp;</strong> {{message}}
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <div class="contact-us-box">
                        <h3 class="title">PRENDRE CONTACT</h3>
                        <p>Contactez-nous pour discuter de vos besoins.<br>
                            N'hésitez pas à nous appeler ou à nous envoyer un message.</p>
                        <form method="POST" action="{% url 'contact' %}">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="row no-gutters">
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="input-box mt-10">
                                        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Votre nom" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="input-box mt-10">
                                        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Adresse e-mail" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="input-box mt-10">
                                        <input type="text" name="number" placeholder="Téléphone" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="input-box mt-10">
                                        <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="Localisation" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="input-box mt-10">
                                        <textarea name="message" id="#" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="écrire un message" required></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my site key"></div>
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                        <button class="main-btn " type="submit" name="formone">Soumettre</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    <!--====== CONTACT US PART ENDS ======-->

    <!--====== CONTACT US PART ENDS ======-->

    

    <!--====== CONTACT US PART ENDS ======-->

    <!--====== SUBSCRIBE PART START ======-->
    
    <div class="subscribe-area subscribe-9-area subscribe-13-area">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="subscribe-item">
                        <h3 class="title">Vous souhaitez améliorer votre communication digitale ?</h3>
                        <span>Inscrivez-vous pour recevoir toutes les astuces et les ressources utiles</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <form role="form" action="{% url 'contact' %}" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="subscribe-form subscribe-9-form subscribe-13-form">
                        <input type="email" name="emails" placeholder="Votre Email" required>
                        <button type="submit" class="main-btn" name="formtwo">Inscription</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <!--====== SUBSCRIBE PART ENDS ======-->
    {% endblock contactpage %}
```

## views.py

```
import json
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from contact.models import ContactMessage, ContactSeoSnippets, ContactSlider
from django.contrib import messages
from emaillist.models import EmailSubs
from homepage.models import SiteSetting

# Create your views here.
def contact(request):
    settings = SiteSetting.objects.all()
    cslider = ContactSlider.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:1]
    c_seo = ContactSeoSnippets.objects.all().order_by('-s_id')[:1]
    context={'settings':settings, 
             'cslider':cslider,  
             'c_seo':c_seo, }
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'contact-us.html',context)
    elif request.method=="POST":
        if 'formone' in request.POST:
            name=request.POST.get('name')
            email=request.POST.get('email')
            number=request.POST.get('number')
            location=request.POST.get('location')
            message=request.POST.get('message')
            en=ContactMessage(name=name,email=email,message=message,number=number,location=location)
            en.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Votre message a été envoyé avec succès')
            
            clientkey = request.POST['g-recaptcha-response']
            secretkey = 'secret key of mine'
            captchaData = {
                'secret': secretkey,
                'response': clientkey
            }
            r= request.post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', data=captchaData)
            response = json.loads(r)
            verify = response
            return redirect('contact') 
        if 'formtwo' in request.POST:
            emails=request.POST.get('emails')
            email=EmailSubs(emails=emails)
            email.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Merci de nous abonner')
        return render(request, 'contact-us.html',context, verify)
```

```
#urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.contact, name="contact"),
]
```

Comment: Can you post your URLs.py with the contact page url?

Comment: added the urls.py